# Is it a good idea to update fields in migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I need an extra field for custom sorting for my `Profile` model. So i need to initialize it on column addition.

Now I see two approaches to do that:

1. Update field after migrations via rake task or at production console.
2. Write down something like that

   ```
   Profile.all.each { |p| p.update_attribute :sorted_at, p.created_at }
   ```

   in separate migration file.

Is second solution good or bad? And may be is there 3rd solution which is much better than these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is to update the fields in the migration.

Pros:

- That's what migrations are for (?)
- No more hassles with tasks. Because one can easily forget to run the task, and in the case of errors or exceptions you have only one place to look at instead of 2.

Cons:

- none that i can think of

Also, it's a good idea to use `update_all` instead of looping through each record and updating because of the obvious performance increase.

Comment: `sorted_at` field should be equal to `created_at` of each row

Comment: Profile.update_all("sorted_at = created_at"), and I guess you're set

Comment: Up arrow, if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a db:seed rake task which was specifically designed for updating data.  The through was that migrations should just be for schema changes.

However, after trying to keep data changes out of my migrations, I again came to the conclusion that migrations are a good place for them.  After all, what you want is an update to run exactly once, and the migrations keep track of which migrations have run and which need to be run, so they run exactly once.

My rule of thumb is:

1. Put it in the seeds.rb script if it is initial data, which has to be in a database for the application to run.  That is, it's part of the initial state, as delivered to the customer.  There is no user interface.  There can never be a valid state if the data were later deleted.  An example would be workflow steps.

I have seeds.rb call other scripts for each table, like seed_workflow_steps.rb.  Also, seed scripts should be written to be run even after the data is in the table.  They should not be for data where there is a user interface where a user might intentionally delete a record, because if the seed task is run again, it will put it back and undo the user's change.

2. You can put it in the migration, but only if it's the migration for creating the table or field that would store it.  In other words, you are initializing the new table or column to an initial state, for it's initial delivery, so it's not blank the first time the feature appears.  This has the advantage that the down migration will drop the table or field, and take care of undoing the population of the data.

3. Otherwise, put it in a rake task or a script and run the task or script as a deployment step.  A good complete development process should have a way for developers to document such extra steps for the deployment.